# How to place image and text next to each where their alignment changes with browser window size in HTML?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a newbie using bootstrap 3 for my website.

I'm trying to place an image next to some text, such that for large browser windows they sit horizontally side by side, but as the browser window is resized smaller, eventually they are stacked vertically (the image first, then the text below it).

Is this possible using HTML & CSS somehow?

Comment: Try `<img src="imgPath.here" alt="" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <span class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">Text Here</span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to wrap them in a row and then col-spans. It should look something like this.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p>This is the text you want.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Assuming you're referencing your stylesheets correctly, this should do the trick. You will find this pretty well documented: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic

Comment: Thanks @morganjlopes, it's working. I'll read up on the link.

Comment: Great! You can also set the columns on different resolutions by using class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6"

Comment: @morganjlopes `col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6` is somewhat redundant. As Bootstrap 3 follows a mobile-first design, writing `class="col-xs-6"` would serve the same purpose. So, you need to define the `sm`, `md` and `lg` classes only if you want to modify the column-count in those views

Comment: @tewathia, sounds good. Was trying to point out that col-xs col-sm col-md could all be used within the same div, not necessarily recommending them as actually classes. Thanks for the clarification though.